# Display Dynamic child Value in a popup form by clicking its parent header in php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, popup, bootstrap-modal, facebox

I have multiple dynamic header something like below image. Every header contails its dynamic child value. when i will click on the header it will display only its child dynamic value in a popup form. I tried 'facebox' and bootstrap modal but can't happen anything. Anybody please solve this problem.
thanks in advance.
mentioned that child value is stored in the unordered list.
  [image]

Structured of form which contains dynamic value something looks like this...

```
<ul>
<li>
  <h4>Sparkle</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 1 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 2 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 3 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 4 </a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<!-- This is the list item that is open by default -->
<li class="active">
  <h4>IDG</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 1 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 2 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 3 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 4 </a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
```

Comment: which value u want to show in popup among the 4 of child `<li>`

Comment: every <li> i want to display

Comment: than u need to give some class or id in `<ul>` than based on this u can get all the child node

Comment: is there any example??? i think i have to change the id or attribute dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this and change according to your need

```
<ul id="column1">
       <li rel="1">Item 1</li>
       <li rel="2">Item 2</li>
       <li rel="3">Item 3</li>
       <li rel="4">Item 4</li>
    </ul>

<script>
    $('ul li').each(function(i)
    {
       $(this).attr('rel'); // This is your rel value
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this before but here the problem is 'rel' is same for each <li> in my code

Comment: ok than make a new `attr` with some unique value and get all the li value based on new attr

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="#myDiv" class="various">Sparkle</a>
   <ul id="myDiv" style="display:none">
    <li><a href="#"> Item 1 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 2 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 3 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item 4 </a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
<li>
 <a href="#myDivv" class="various">IDG</a>
  <ul id="myDivv" style="display:none">
   <li><a href="#"> Test 1 </a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Test 2 </a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Test 3 </a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Test 4 </a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){       
$(".various").fancybox({
maxWidth      : 800,
maxHeight     : 600,
fitToView     : false,
width           : '70%',
height        : '70%',
autoSize      : false,
closeClick  : false,
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
autoScale: false,
padding: 0,
closeClick: false,

beforeLoad: function () {
  var url = $(this.element).attr("id");
  this.href = url
}
});

});
</script>
```